# Compare firebase value with an integer

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to compare firebase data with an integer but the app crashes.
here is the code:

```
 Firebase myfirebase; int result = 500;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
    myfirebase = new Firebase("https://analog-85958.firebaseio.com/number");
    myfirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String mychildtext = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mytextview.setText(mychildtext);

            int num = Integer.parseInt(mychildtext);
            if (num == result)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
```

Database Structure:

[image]

Comment: don't post code as image

Comment: I suggest you to read Firebase's documentation

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a String and you have an int in your database:

```
  @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String mychildtext = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); //here
            mytextview.setText(mychildtext);

            int num = Integer.parseInt(mychildtext);
```

First get the value like this:

```
int mychildtext = Integer.valueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue().toString());
```

You can also try this to get the value:

```
int mychildtext = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

And then:

```
mytextview.setText(mychildtext);
```

and for the last part use your value here:

```
int num = mychildtext;

     if (num == result)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Edit: I think your reference is wrong, change it like this:

```
String url = "https://analog-85958.firebaseio.com/number";
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
              

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ....
```

Comment: App crashes again

Comment: i think your reference is wrong , where do you have DatabaseReference ?

Comment: still its crashing

Comment: its working when i read data as string. But i want to compare that value with an integer.

Comment: @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String mychildtext = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mytextview.setText(mychildtext);

Comment: you are geting the value and you set that to your textview, you are not comparing any value there

Comment: do you have any suggestion for comparing the data with an integer.

Comment: when you get the value into mychildtext you can do anything you want with it inside ondatachanged

Comment: just get the data as an integer like i answer and you will not have any problem, the thing is that you are parsing an integer value from your database as a string and then converting that to an integer again